# libGL can't find anything related to DRI on ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, xorg, opengl, nouveau

When running programs that use opengl, I keep getting errors about how libGL can't find nouveau_dri.so

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, and as is default, I am using nouveau, but it seems there is an incompatibility of some sort with libGL and the nouveau that comes with Ubuntu. Please help me figure out why libGL is not working correctly and how to rectify this.

When I run `LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose glxinfo | grep libgl`, I get [this](https://pastebin.com/FW18ECTR).

The output of `grep DRI /var/log/Xorg.0.log` is [this](https://pastebin.com/rKtvaHKy)

Output of `xdpyinfo | grep DRI` is `DRI2 DRI3`

Finally, the output of `dpkg -L xserver-xorg-video-nouveau` is

```
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/xorg
/usr/lib/xorg/modules
/usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers
/usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
/usr/share
/usr/share/bug
/usr/share/bug/xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
/usr/share/doc/xserver-xorg-video-nouveau/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/xserver-xorg-video-nouveau/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/xserver-xorg-video-nouveau/copyright
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man4
/usr/share/man/man4/nouveau.4.gz
/usr/share/bug/xserver-xorg-video-nouveau/script
```

EDIT in response to comment:
I ran the command as instructed, so it appears I do have the .so, but how do I tell libGL where to look?

```
$ apt-file search nouveau_dri.so
libgl1-mesa-dri: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so
```

Comment: Try installing the libgl1-mesa-dri package: $ apt-file search nouveau_dri.so
libgl1-mesa-dri: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so

Comment: @ubfan1 It is already installed by default ```libgl1-mesa-dri/jammy-updates,now 22.0.1-1ubuntu2.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  free implementation of the OpenGL API -- DRI modules
```

Comment: Are this 32-bit or 64-bit applications?

Comment: Run ldd on the program complaining, and see where is is looking for the library. Kluge would be to simply add a link to the lib in the necessary place if it's 64 bit. Add 32 bit pkg if necessary..

Comment: @ubfan1 Ok I see how that could work and thank you, but yeah that is a bit hacky, there's no way to configure where mesa-loader looks?